# How do I go make my Python code more efficient and dynamic?

Tags: python, class, sharing

I'm a trainee novice programmer.

I have / am creating simple programs, generally around screen scraping, data caption (postrgres), various processing methods and now a GUI via wxpython

I find a lot of these programs overlap - ie use same techniques, and get some very long copied and pasted programs!

Overtime I improve these techniques and find myself having to backtrack over multiple programs to update these.

> How? Can I? Create a more dynamic, systematic process.
>
> One where all programs / procedures / classes are shared?
>
> Has it got a name?

My logical thought is that like 'procedures' and 'classes' I have would have smaller low level programs and mid level programs that called upon these - the GUI being the top program! but this would mean passing data to and from! Can Classes and Procedures be separate programs?

Many thanks
Cameron

Comment: In python it's called [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). And it's a natural way to organize programs. Please read the [documentation on packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html)

Comment: Thank you John, I'll look deeper! Obviously people must think its a very stupid question with a negative score. But if you dont know! You ask! Thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but a problem with your question is that this is not about "dynamism", but rather about "code reuse".

Comment: Tripleee - I've altered the title! Although I still think 'dynamic' is relevant especially in light of the guidance given. Dynamic = "characterized by constant change, activity, or progress"

Comment: How can it be too broad - it been answered three times! 3 hours ago I hadn't a clue on how to make my programming more efficient! Now I know which way to go!

Comment: I don't understand the mods decision either. The question sounds broad, but there's pretty much only one good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a range of techniques you can use :

1. Shared modules - A set of modules with well defined interfaces - functions, classes etc. These modules sit in a folders which every application you use can get to - i.e. the path to the folder is added to PYTHON_PATH environment variable. These interfaces should be engineered so when you add functionality to them they don't break the old applications.

   Design patterns - Design your applications with a good design pattern - MVC (Master View Controller) is a useful one for GUI programs. V is your GUI - and exposes only a few methods, which aren't actually dependent on the GUI itself (for instances methods such as display_foo). The Master is your data access functionality - again with well defined interfaces. Controller interfaces between View and Master. There may be other patterns which apply to your application too.

Comment: Many thanks - You've dangled the carrot with MVC, but I think I will have to start by learning to walk, with the "Shared Modules". An hour ago I hadn't a clue! Now I'm wanting to build my own "OpenERP" program. Funny how information snippets from the past re-emerge!

Answer (score 1):

For a small scale project, you can create a workspace directory like this:

```
-MyWorkspace
    -Program1.py
    -Program2.py
    -SharedModules
        -Classes.py
        -Functions.py
        -Decorators.py
```

And then in your python program you can do, for example:

```
from SharedModules.Functions import foo, bar
from SharedModules.Classes import Spam
```

Again, this will work for small scale workspaces. If you'll find yourself working on something more sophisticated and big it might get too messy.

Comment: Many thanks - I think I can see where I have to start!